# CS0103: I can't use methods through classes (basic level)

Tags: c#, class

I'm trying to run a method created in a different class using the "public" access modifier. It seems not to be working like fields. Here's a simple example, could you lead me to a solution?
Thank you.

```
class Program
{
    void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Hello();
    }
}

class Example
{
   public void Hello() //Error?
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to read up on instance methods, creating new instances of classes and probably static methods, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the 'Example' class in able to call it's 'Hello' method:

```
class Program
{
    void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var example = new Example();       
      example.Hello();
    }
}

class Example
{
   public void Hello() //Error?
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
   }
}
```

Or: make the Hello method static:

```
class Program
{
    void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Example.Hello();
    }
}

class Example
{
   public static void Hello()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just as an example: you need to instantiate an object of the class first to be able to access its members (unless they are static):

```
class Program
{
    void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Example ex = new Example();
       ex.Hello();
    }
}

class Example
{
   public void Hello()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
   }
}
```